# Having troubles with a custom task process in SPD 2010

Tags: 2010, workflow, sharepoint-designer

I'm building a WF with SPD 2010 that spawn a custom task process.

When the WF starts, I got an error. The ULS log show me :

```
06/10/2011 12:38:46.23  w3wp.exe (0x1FF8)   0x0A98  SharePoint Foundation   Workflow Infrastructure 72ew    Medium  Object reference not set to an instance of an object.   93ebccd3-d4f4-44e9-8ca3-4bf4c0114251
06/10/2011 12:38:46.29  w3wp.exe (0x1FF8)   0x0A98  SharePoint Foundation   Workflow Infrastructure 88xr    Unexpected  WinWF Internal Error, terminating workflow Id# e684e09e-efd0-45f5-8e9d-04ea362f6d4d 93ebccd3-d4f4-44e9-8ca3-4bf4c0114251
06/10/2011 12:38:46.29  w3wp.exe (0x1FF8)   0x0A98  SharePoint Foundation   Workflow Infrastructure 98d4    Unexpected  System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.     at Microsoft.Office.Workflow.Actions.OfficeTask.ProcessTaskError(Object sender, EventArgs e)     at System.Workflow.ComponentModel.ActivityExecutorDelegateInfo`1.ActivityExecutorDelegateOperation.Run(IWorkflowCoreRuntime workflowCoreRuntime)     at System.Workflow.Runtime.Scheduler.Run()   93ebccd3-d4f4-44e9-8ca3-4bf4c0114251
06/10/2011 12:38:46.34  w3wp.exe (0x1FF8)   0x0A98  InfoPath Forms Services Runtime 961x    Medium  Not persisting state for request due to previous errors. Form Template: urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:infopath:workflowInitAssoc:-AutoGen-2011-06-10T09:29:52:667Z   93ebccd3-d4f4-44e9-8ca3-4bf4c0114251
```

this is not very helpful...

Adding some logs in the WF, I can see that the "Before assignation" is called, but not the "After creation" (not sure of the label as my SPD is in french).

What are my options to isolate the problem ?

thx

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like the Association or Initiation form is not serializing correctly when starting the workflow. I might try deleting and letting SPD2010 re-create your Association form. Did you customize it?

Comment: already tried, without success.